# type cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, xml

i have just started building android application. And this error

> button cannot be resolved to a type

constantly bugs me. here is the java code

```
package com.android.revision1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Revision1Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button=(Button) findViewByid(R.layout.button1);
}
}
```

Here is the Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`button` seems undeclared, so declare that field

```
private Button button;
```

or local variable:

```
Button button=(Button) findViewByid(R.layout.button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your variable is declared and you just aren't showing it, you need to import the Button class. Add the following line next to your other imports:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `button` as it's currently not declared before being set.

Here is the complete code:

```
package com.android.revision1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Revision1Activity extends Activity {

    private Button button; // this is what you are missing

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button=(Button) findViewByid(R.layout.button1);
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same error exists, i think there is some issue wit R class or some issue with eclipse,. Is there any possibility of that..?

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse? Google is dropping support for it 100% at the end of the year, I recommend switching to Android Studio. Regardless of the R file is causing problems do a clean/rebuild on the project and it should regenerate the R file.